# WCF service is not getting callled when proxy server for LAN enabled

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, proxy

I tried a simple REST service with JSON using WCF, that works fine initially and when i go to Internet Option -> Connections -> LAN settings -> Proxy Server settings -> and I set the  Adress and Port at this scenarion servise is not returning JSON output. but this works in IE and it's not working in chrome and firefox.

I don't know why it's not working when proxy is enabled. and this is working if we check the Bypass proxy server for local server

App.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
         <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="http://192.156.23.123:8080" bypassonlocal="True"/>
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
    <system.serviceModel>
       <services>
           <service name = "abc">
             <host>
               <baseAddress>
                   <add baseAdress="http://localhost:8712"/>
               </baseAddress>
             </host>
             <endpoint adress = "" behaviorConfiguration="rest"binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFservicelibrary1.Iservice1">
              <identity>
               <dns value = "localhost"/>
              </identity>
             </endpoint>
             <enspoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
             </service>
       </services>
       <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
           <behavior name = "rest">
              <webHttp/>
           </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</<configuration>
```

Comment: did you check the proxy settings in chrome. Also try to set the proxy details in the control panel > internet options > Connections > LAN Settings and give chrome and firefox a try,

Comment: Thanks saravanan but we can set the above LAN settings from Internet options also right even this also opens the same window

Comment: Did you also verify the proxy settings in chrome. Also if required, you can mark the url in the list of allowed url's

Comment: If i tried to set the proxy settings from chrome it navigates to the same window as what you said